# "is proven" or "are proven" in this sentence?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

- This is my version:

Metallo-organic anti-wear additive system in Havoline ProDS Fully Synthetic ECO 5and ProDS Fully Synthetic LE SAE 5W-40 **is** proven to protect engines under a broad range of operating conditions for the light duty engines segment.

- That's legal's version:

Metallo-organic anti-wear additive system**s** in Havoline ProDS Fully Synthetic ECO 5and ProDS Fully Synthetic LE SAE 5W-40 **are** proven to protect engines under a broad range of operating conditions for the light duty engines segment.

**Which one is correct?**

Comment: If it's a single product, use **is**. If 2 products are concerned, use **are**. Whatever the case, the sentence is a mouthful.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a single system as a whole, or is the emphasis on multiple systems working together? That's a technical question so I doubt any of us can answer it, but you just need to decide *how* you're talking about the thing, whether it's singular or plural, and then write it accordingly.

If you *are* going with the singular version, you need a determiner like *the* (or *this* or whatever) when referring to *system*.

Comment: It's a single system. I just double checked from the reference article (internal brochure). "**metallo-organic anti-wear additive system** provides excellent protection against wear of critically loaded components under all operating conditions. "

So i take it the sentence becomes ' is proven to protect engines' in this case, correct?

Comment: Well, things are made up of multiple components, and often several substances are used together, each performing some kind of important role. *Additive systems* **could** mean multiple formulations of... stuff... that's combined into the... I'm assuming it's some kind of lubricant? So the emphasis might be on the different additives (plural) that have been included to create the final product, with all its properties. That's what I mean about whether you're focused on the thing as a whole (the final product) or the stuff that goes into it (multiple "systems", as the chemicals might be called)